# rails trouble with nested resources and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been using the

```
to_param
    username
end
```

in my user model so that I can access users by /user/username (instead of ID)

I'm trying to make links to user listings (listings is a nested resource) with:

`@listings` represent a query on the Listing model

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>

  <%= link_to 'Show', user_listings_url(listing.user_id, listing) %>

<% end %>
```

But its giving me the user_id instead and I tried querying the listing.user_id into the users model but it just returned and object and I can't get the simple user/username/listing path to work :/ Any help? Should I not be using to_param?

Comment: try `user_listings_url(listing.user, listing)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', user_listings_url([listing.user, listing]) %>
<% end %>
```

this will link to `/user/username/listings/listing_id`

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can even just do `<%= link_to 'Show', [listing.user, listing] %>`, as Rails will figure out what you mean and convert it to `<%= link_to 'Show', user_listings_path([listing.user, listing]) %>`.